# Some apps' windows won't stay on my MacBook screen

Tags: display, macbook

When I try to use two apps (first HPSmart and now TextEdit), their window just flashes onto my screen for a split second and then disappears. I can see it open when I press F3, and the dot appears under the icon in my Dock to show it's open, but I can't click on it to use the window or any part of the app. I tried re-starting my browser, and then re-booted the whole computer, and that didn't help. I also tried Force Quit and relaunching the apps, but that didn't help either. I tried shutting down the printer (when it was just HP Smart that wasn't working, but now TextEdit is down too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this…

Quit both apps
Switch to Finder
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Finder Window
 <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>   for Go To
Copy paste `~/Library/Saved Application State/` & hit Enter
Scroll down to find `com.apple.TextEdit.savedState`
Delete *the contents of* the folder [not the folder itself]
Scroll down to find folders starting with `com.hp. …`
Again, delete the contents of each [there may be a few HP folders, so clear them all]

Try launching your apps again.

Comment: I tried this and now Finder is not appearing, either.

Comment: What's missing from Finder? Windows, icons, menu bar? Check resource usage in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as this, it's because your HP Smart App is not updated. after I updated the software, this problem was resolved. Try updating the HP Smart APP and try running it again. I downloaded it at [HP Smart App](https://dlutilities.com/hp-smart/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).